# Php, fill image from raw memory, idea?

Tags: php, gdi

Im processing images from Php and I need to make a PNG from raw memory area. This memory area-format can be indexed (bytes) or RGB (R, G, B byte-byte-byte).
Basically it works like this for now:

```
for($i=0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<100; $j++)
    {
        $byte = fread($F, pack('C');
        // or
        $R = fread($F, pack('C');
        $G = fread($F, pack('C');
        $B = fread($F, pack('C');

        imagesetpixel($img, $j, $i, imagecolorallocate($img, $R,$G,$B);
    }
}
```

and this is kinda slow. Im sure there must be a better way, any ideas?

Comment: Other than "caching" the result of `imagecolorallocate` for colors you already encountered, I don't think there is much that can be improved here. If you need to set pixel by pixel, that's just going to take a certain amount of time ...

Comment: Maybe you can "create" a bitmap image out of your data first? You'd have to get the necessary headers correct (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure), but then you should be able to more or less "dump" your existing pixel data into there. And then you could read that bitmap image using PHP, and convert it to another format like JPEG or PNG.

Comment: It's very slow to read/write the image pixel by pixel in PHP. This is usually done in low level languages like c. Even then, most c or c++ programmers stay away from it, and they use image libraries instead. The standard PHP image library should offer most common functions you want, for example writing text on the image, or changing color scale. There should be other libraries with more advanced functions.